# Rendering dynamic cube maps in OpenGL with frame buffer objects

Tags: opengl, dynamic, dictionary, buffer, cube

I am attempting to dynamically generate cube-maps in OpenGL using a multi-pass rendering system. The method I am using successfully renders the scene to a frame buffer object (tested with glReadPixels). The frame buffer is attached to a texture, the target of which is GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB. I have verified that the frame buffer contents **do** end up in the texture by querying the bound texture with glGetTexImage and writing the contents to disk.

However, when I bind the cube map in order to render it onto an object, the texture is not visible on the mesh.

The process is as follows:

1) Unbind all textures from GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB

2) Bind the frame buffer object.

3) Attach the texture to target GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT of the frame buffer.  I start with the positive-x side of the cube (GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X_ARB).  The others follow in subsequent passes.

4) Attach a depth render buffer to target GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT of the frame buffer.

5) Direct rendering to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT with glDrawBuffer.

6) Render the scene along the appropriate axis.

7) With the frame buffer still bound, detach the texture with glFramebufferTexture2DEXT.

8) Unbind the frame buffer and redirect rendering to GL_BACK with glDrawBuffer.

9) Repeat steps 1-8 for all sides of the cube map.

10) Bind the final cube map texture and render the final scene.  A GLSL shader is used to calculate texture coordinates.

This technique is based on notes available [here](http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~tmcgraw/cs570spring2010/lecture6-2010.pdf).

Debugging steps taken thus-far:

I) Loaded a static cube map from disk to test the shader.  It works as expected.

II) Queried the contents of the frame buffer using glReadPixels during the first 6 passes. The scene appeared as it should.

III) Copied the contents of the cube map using glGetTexImage after rendering completed. Wrote the contents to disk as an image file. The various sides of the cube appeared as they should.

I can only conclude that the frame buffer/texture are being rendered-to correctly.  For whatever reason, I cannot get the resulting texture to appear on the final mesh. The texture is definitely bound prior to the final rendering pass and GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB is enabled.

As noted in the procedure outlined above, the texture is unbound prior to frame buffer rendering so as to avoid read/write conflicts.  Similarly, the texture is detached from the frame buffer after each and every pass for the same reason.

At first I was concerned that my re-use of GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT triggered the problem. This now seems unlikely given step III of my debugging process.  Moreover, I have found references on internet forums to people doing the same without issue.

This is taking place on an NVIDIA 9400M (Mac OS X).  OpenGL Extension Viewer reports that I have all the necessary extensions to perform this operation.

Any insight into what might be causing this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to produce my own answer not 6 minutes later. In my defence, the reason was a bit odd.

Elsewhere in the program I had enabled GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_SGIS, the extension responsible for generating mipmaps.  I neglected to specify the mipmap LOD when calling glFramebufferTexture2DEXT.

Seems like these two things combined disabled the texture in the final pass. Turning GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_SGIS off while rendering the cube map solves the problem.

Cheers.